# Stopping services from being restarted as a result of dist-upgrade replacing a dependency

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, systemd

Running Ubuntu Server 18.04

I believe I've encountered the following situation, and would like to stop it from occurring again.

The situation:

1/ I've put docker on hold with apt mark. This is confirmed with I do `sudo apt upgrade --simulate`, it correctly states:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

2/ Someone performs `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. This causes a shared dependency to be updated. Which in turn forces the docker service to restart, causing all containers to be restarted as well.

That's what I think happened. I'd like to prevent this from happening.

Is there a way to achieve this? The notion of docker, and all running containers, being restarted suddenly because of an event like this is bad news and I've frankly never heard of this happening before.

Is this possible? And if so, how do I prevent it? I would hope there's a way to basically say "This dependency is also used by a service that is not permitted to be automatically restarted, so don't upgrade it".

Comment: I don't think there are packages called `containerd.io` or `docker-ce` in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Similar StackOverflow question from 2016: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765518/prevent-docker-engine-restart-during-apt-get-upgrade

Comment: Take a look at [Docker Live Restore](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/)